# Get Selected Item from Windows Phone listbox in Hold event

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox

I have a pretty basic Listbox in my Windows phone 8 app.  It's not data bound to anything, it's just an empty listbox.

```
<ListBox Margin="0,10" Name="lstStops" SelectionChanged="favouriteSelection" 
 Hold="favouriteSelectionHold" FontSize="28">
    <ListBox.Items>

    </ListBox.Items>
</ListBox>
```

I want to be able to give the user the option to delete items from this list by pressing and holding on the item.  I have added an onHold event which is firing when the user presses on an item in the list and holds but I don't know how to find out which actual entry in the listbox they have selected.

How can I find out which item they have pressed and held on?

This is how the Listbox is populated:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Object> entry in IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings)
{
    lstStops.Items.Add(entry.Key as String + " - " + entry.Value as String);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been asked many times. There are different ways to achieve this. Read more [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/wp7-listbox-selecteditem).

One way includes getting the datacontext of the sender and casting it to your Item type.

EDIT: Since it's a bunch of strings, the way to extract the string can be:

```
private void favouriteSelectionHold(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    string n = (e.OriginalSource as TextBlock).Text;
}
```

This works only if your DataTemplate is not defined differently.

Comment: Thanks but I know how to grab the selecteditem when the Selection changes.  The issue is finding the selecteditem when the hold event fires, rather than the Selection Changed event.

Comment: @irldev What is the type of the Item you're adding to the list, a simple string?

Comment: It's a KeyValuePair<string, Object> Dictionary that I iterate through and add the key and values to the listbox.

Comment: @irldev can you add more code to your question to make it more clear - how do you populate the listbox and the item class implementation? Then it'll be easier for me to answer correctly.

Comment: Added to the original question.

Comment: @irldev added one way of extracting the string to my answer.