# How do I get item on listBox hold event in Windows Phone

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, listboxitem

how do I get item on listbox hold event in windows phone?
suppose I have three items in listbox,

```
1 - abc
2 - def
3 - ghi
```

If I hold on item "abc" then how do I get that item?

Comment: Try to use search option first: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269244/how-to-implement-hold-in-listbox), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173769/get-selected-item-from-windows-phone-listbox-in-hold-event) and more.

Comment: @Viraj Shah could you share your listbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this helps you.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstBoxTemp" Hold="lstBoxTemp_Hold">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
     .......
     ........
     Your template
    </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

private void lstBoxTemp_Hold(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
         var item= (Cast as YourType)(sender as ListBox).DataContext;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

This would help you to get list item on hold event:

```
private void lst_Hold_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {       
            string text = (e.OriginalSource as TextBlock).Text;
        }
```